# Swift UIViewController subclass variable in protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

My idea is to have a common router that I could use for common method that I use across my app. But I get this error and I want to keep `weak var viewController` as a HomeViewController
How can I get it to work ?

> Type 'HomeRouter' does not conform to protocol 'CommonRoutingLogic'

```swift
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var router: HomeRoutingLogic?
    
    func detailsClicked() {
        router?.goToDetails()
    }
}

class HomeRouter: CommonRoutingLogic {
    weak var viewController: HomeViewController?

    init(viewController: HomeViewController?) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}

protocol HomeRoutingLogic: CommonRoutingLogic {
    func displayHomeGreetings()
}

protocol CommonRoutingLogic {
    var viewController: UIViewController? { get set }
    func goToDetails()
}

extension CommonRoutingLogic {
    func goToDetails() {
        // goto details
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you've declared `viewController` to be of type `HomeViewController?`, but the protocol requires it to be of type `UIViewController?`. You cannot override the type even with a subclass, protocol requirements need to be matched exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are not implementing the goToDetails() method.
Maybe changin this:

```
extension CommonRoutingLogic {
func goToDetails() {
    // goto details
}
```

}

to this?

```
extension HomeRouter : CommonRoutingLogic {
func goToDetails() {
    // goto details
}
```

}

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue. The problem comes from `viewController` having the wrong type.